# Understanding a Structure / Linked List

Tags: c, list, structure

I came across this structures and I am having a hard time "dissecting" them, both because I write them differently and because I'm dumb.

Here's the structures:

```
typedef struct no_disciplina * ListDisciplinas;

typedef struct no_disciplina 
{     
     char * nome;    
     struct no_apont_aluno * alunos;     
     ListDisciplinas next; 
} NoDisciplina;

typedef struct no_aluno * ListAlunos; 

typedef struct no_aluno 
{     
     char * nome;
     int numero;
     struct no_apont_disciplina * disciplinas;
     ListAlunos next;
 } NoAluno; 

 typedef struct no_apont_disciplina * ListApontDisciplinas;

 typedef struct no_apont_disciplina
 {    ListDisciplinas disciplina;
      ListApontDisciplinas next;
 } NoApontDisciplina; 

typedef struct no_apont_aluno * ListApontAlunos;

typedef struct no_apont_aluno
{     
     ListAlunos aluno;
     ListApontAlunos next;
} NoApontAluno;
```

Also it is said that these linked lists don't have a header (a node solely composed of a pointer to the first "real" node of the list) so how do i define it?

Thanks in advance :D!

Answer (score 0):

So you would define your linked list like so,

```
typedef struct node {
    char val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

Then to use the linked list with a head you would do something like this,

```
node_t * head = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
if (head == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

head->val = 'a';
head->next = NULL;
```

So now 'head' will be your header and any subsequent nodes you define will be attached to the 'head' with the last element being the tail.

Comment: So i'm guessing the line typedef struct no_disciplina * ListDisciplinas; makes an header of the list?